# Having an issue with adding and deleting values in a JQuery array based upon clicked divs

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Here is my JQuery:

```
var skinCare=[];

$('.skinCare').click(function(){
    if($.inArray(event.target.id, skinCare) == -1){
        var value = event.target.id;
        skinCare.push(value);
    }
    var index = skinCare.indexOf(value);
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'){
        skinCare.splice(skinCare.indexOf(index), 1);
    }
});
$('html').click(function(){
    alert(skinCare);
});
```

This is the HTML I am showing for users to click on:

```
<a href="#item4" class="panel"><div class="nextButton"></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="acne" style="top:10px;left:265px"><div class="inner_circle" id="acne">ACNE/</br>BLEMISHES</div></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="dry_skin" style="top:255px;left:10px"><div class="inner_circle" id="dry_skin">DRY SKIN</div></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="oily_skin" style="top:90px;left:100px"><div class="inner_circle" id="oily_skin">OILY SKIN/LARGE PORES</div></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="aging" style="top:90px;left:430px"><div class="inner_circle" id="aging">WRINKLES/</br>AGING</div></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="irritation" style="top:255px;left:510px"><div class="inner_circle" id="irritation">SENSATIVE SKIN/IRRITATION</div></div></a>
                <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="dark_spots" style="top:430px;left:100px"><div class="inner_circle" id="dark_spots">DARK SPOTS</div></div></a>
```

Right now I have the JQuery set up so that if the background color of the div being clicked on is a certain color (set by a css class when clicked), it either adds or deletes a value in the array, skinCare.  I am completely open to any options that work, however, and do not need to do it by color.  I just want a value to be added to a JQuery array if a div is clicked, then if it is clicked again, to be deleted from the array.

Comment: You already asked 5 questions without saying "thanks", accepting or even leaving **`1`** constructive comment to the people who gave their time to help you. Please make sure to review your *old* questions, leave a feedback and **accept** all the answers that were most helpful in resolving your issues.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've gone back and reviewed my old questions.  I didn't realize I could accept because I had tried to vote up some answers but it said I didn't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect to use the same `id` for multiple HTML elements. This is quite likely the cause of your problem.

Also, <s>please review</s> *I thank you for that you reviewed* the comment from @roXon.

Comment: I got rid of the duplicate id's, but for some reason when I deselect a div (click it a second time) it only takes away the last value that was added.

Comment: Good point. Is there something that changes the background color of the div? The jQuery code above doesn't seem to do that. Or maybe the thing is that, in the line `var index = skinCare.indexOf(value);`, the `value` doesn't seem to be initialized unless `event.target.id` is not in `skinCare`. I don't actually know jQuery well, so I could be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes there is a .click function that changes the color.  even.target.id refers to the id of the div I clicked on, which is the value that gets passed into the array skinCare.  So index is just the position in skinCare.

Comment: I recall that there is, or at least used to be, something really strange about where `var` takes effect when the nearest block around it is not a function definition. Nevertheless, am I right that `value` doesn't get updated when you click the div for the second time, because `value` gets updated only in the `if` block? `if($.inArray(event.target.id, skinCare) == -1){ var value = event.target.id; ...`

Comment: Yes I believe you're correct.  The value variable is only updated with the if statement.  I will try playing around with value to get it in the right place.

Comment: I've changed the .skinCare click function to this:
$('.skinCare').click(function(){
  var value = event.target.id;
  var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
  if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){
      skinCare.push(value);
  }
  
  else{
   skinCare.splice(skinCare.indexOf(index), 1);
  }
 });

However I'm getting the same results where it only deletes the last added value.