# Add and remove div class to jquery array or json object when div is clicked

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, class, html

Basically what I want to do is have a div that, once clicked, the child's class is added to a JQuery array or even a JSON object.  Once the div is clicked again, I want the class to be removed from the array.  Multiple divs must be able to be "selected" and deselected.

I have been successful in adding a child class or id to the array, as shown here:

```
var skinCare=[];
    $('.skinCare').click(function(){
        var value = event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
        var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
        if($('.skinCare').hasClass('selected')){
            //$('.skinCare').removeClass('selected');
            skinCare.splice(skinCare.indexOf(index), 1);
        }
```

However I have not been able to accomplish removing it from the array:

```
else if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){

            skinCare.push(value);
        }
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle I made that shows what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/bzYCm/

By the way, this is an update of a problem I was having a day or two ago.  The issue remained unresolved so I reworked what I had and I think I am asking the question better now.

Here is the post from the other day: [Having an issue with adding and deleting values in a JQuery array based upon clicked divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469209/having-an-issue-with-adding-and-deleting-values-in-a-jquery-array-based-upon-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test `$('.skinCare').hasClass('selected')` is wrong as it tests for whether the first element with class `skinCare` has the class `selected`. Instead you need to test whether the clicked element has the class `selected`, it is done by `$(this).hasClass('selected')`.

```
var skinCare=[];
$('.skinCare').click(function(){
    var value = event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
    var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        //$('.skinCare').removeClass('selected');
        skinCare.splice(index, 1);
    } else if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){
        skinCare.push(value);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MWcfG/2/)

Comment: I added this to my fiddle but it removes the last added class instead of the one that was just deselected.

When I went to your fiddle it did the same as my original.

Comment: `skinCare.splice(skinCare.indexOf(index), 1);` also is wrong, it should be `skinCare.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: It seems to work in the jsfiddle, but when I copy the code to my live site, it doesn't work?  Any ideas?
http://dev.chrisruno.com/sahshe/quiz/

Comment: can you do a `console.log(index, skinCare)` and see what is happening

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # jquery.min.js:4
st.error jquery.min.js:4
ft jquery.min.js:4
st jquery.min.js:4
b.fn.extend.find jquery.min.js:4
b.fn.b.init jquery.min.js:3
b jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery.scrollTo.js:130
b.extend.each jquery.min.js:3
b.fn.b.each jquery.min.js:3
$.fn.scrollTo jquery.scrollTo.js:114
(anonymous function) myjs.js:10
b.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
v.handle jquery.min.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined myjs.js:106
(anonymous function) myjs.js:106
b.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
v.handle`

Answer (score 0):

> it's about timing between the function add the class and the function
>   that evaluates "hasClass" you must evaluates if exist on the array
>   insted if has the class...
>
> ### > [Zach Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536055/jquery-works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-live-site)

This worked:

```
var skinCare = [];
        $('.skinCare').click(function(){
            var value = event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
            var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
            if(index >= 0){
                skinCare.splice(index, 1);
            } else if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){
                skinCare.push(value);
            }
        });
```