# JQuery works in JSFiddle but not Live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CR47/w45M8/

Here's the Live site:
http://dev.chrisruno.com/sahshe/quiz/#index3

And yes, my index is properly linking to JQuery library and my .js files.  Other javascript from all the files are working, it is only the part that I had done in JSFiddle that does not seem to work.  It is actually doing the opposite of what it is supposed to do.

here is a screenshot of it on the live site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgCbf.jpg

```
var skinCare=[];
$('.skinCare').click(function(){
    var value = event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
    var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        //$('.skinCare').removeClass('selected');
        skinCare.splice(index, 1);
    } else if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){
        skinCare.push(value);
    }
});

$('html').click(function(){
    alert(skinCare);

});



    $('.circle').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        });

        $('.circle').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });

        $('.multi').click(function(){
            //$(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
```

I've tried disabling chrome to phone extension as per the suggestion of the chrome forums, but to no avail.
This is what I get in the error console:

```
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # 
jquery.min.js:4 
st.error jquery.min.js:4 
ft jquery.min.js:4 
st jquery.min.js:4 
b.fn.extend.find 
jquery.min.js:4 
b.fn.b.init 
jquery.min.js:3 b jquery.min.js:3 (anonymous function) jquery.scrollTo.js:130 
b.extend.each jquery.min.js:3 
b.fn.b.each jquery.min.js:3 
$.fn.scrollTo jquery.scrollTo.js:114 (anonymous function) 
myjs.js:10 b.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3 
v.handle jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined myjs.js:106 (anonymous function) 
myjs.js:106 
b.event.dispatch 
jquery.min.js:3 v.handle
```

Comment: I got an `unrecognized expression: #` error in the console when clicking.

Comment: I'm getting the same and can't seem to find an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition to add in the array alway is true so never push the value into array

change `if(index >= 0)` insted `$(this).hasClass('selected')`

it's about timing between the function add the class and the function that evaluates "hasClass" you must evaluates if exist on the array insted if has the class...

```
var skinCare = [];
        $('.skinCare').click(function(){
            var value = event.target.className.split(" ")[0];
            var index = skinCare.indexOf(value); 
            if(index >= 0){
                skinCare.splice(index, 1);
            } else if($.inArray(value, skinCare) == -1){
                skinCare.push(value);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please compare the source on your page with the Draft Page. Check if your script loads all the specified libraries (check for 404 errors using the web console in your browser). We do host some of the libraries, please upload them to your site before using.

- draft http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#result-draft
- FAQ http://doc.jsfiddle.net/faq.html#code-is-working-on-jsfiddle-not-on-site-local-machine

Comment: I've edited the question to include my error console reports.